# Handlebars filtering object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using Express, NodeJS and MongoDB . Trying to use handlebars to pass some info to render.

the route code im using is:

```
router.get('/mediciones', async (req, res) => {
  // res.render('mediciones');
  const dashboard  = await Mediciones.find().limit(3);
  console.log(dashboard);
  res.render('mediciones' , { dashboard });
});
```

the hbs code is:

```
{{#each  dashboard }}
<p>
    {{!-- {{this}} --}}      // using just one, but both show me the 3 objects
    {{.}}
</p>
{{/each}}
```

the rendered view:

```
{ _id: 5ea9ff48b54a2b09d38ddfd9, temperatura: 20, humedad: 44, heat: 19.2, temperaturaagua1: 22.31, temperaturaagua2: 22.31, ventilador: true, extractor: true, intractor: true, bombaagua: true, refreshInterval: 10000, currentMillis: 3799956, dia: 2020-04-29T22:27:20.997Z, __v: 0 }

{ _id: 5ea9ff52b54a2b09d38ddfda, temperatura: 20, humedad: 44, heat: 19.2, temperaturaagua1: 22.31, temperaturaagua2: 22.31, ventilador: true, extractor: true, intractor: true, bombaagua: true, refreshInterval: 10000, currentMillis: 3809961, dia: 2020-04-29T22:27:30.986Z, __v: 0 }

{ _id: 5ea9ff5db54a2b09d38ddfdb, temperatura: 20, humedad: 44, heat: 19.2, temperaturaagua1: 22.31, temperaturaagua2: 22.31, ventilador: true, extractor: true, intractor: true, bombaagua: true, refreshInterval: 10000, currentMillis: 3820030, dia: 2020-04-29T22:27:41.068Z, __v: 0 }
```

The problem is: how can i just exract "temperatura" and "humedad" from those objects and print them on a `<p>` tag? i tried to use `{{temperatura}}` but nothing show. I cant find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
try this.

const dashboard  = await Mediciones.find().limit(3).lean();
```

Comment: if i inspect the element in the html i can see three empty p tags, not the values from the object

Comment: same result as before

Comment: "Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "temperatura" because it is not an "own property" of its parent."

Comment: When i console.log dashboard i get an [  {}   , {}  ,  {} ] ,if i change the sentence to findOne(). the console log just gives me a {} and then {{temperatura}} works (just one). if i try to itinerate nothing show

Comment: can you simply add an array in route file arr =[1,2,3] and try to iterate in handlebar. lets see if its working fine

Comment: yes, arr = [ {temperatura: 20},{temperatura: 30},{temperatura: 40}] works well

Comment: can you try to convert your data  dashboard = dashboard.toJSON() in route file

Comment: you can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753149/express-handlebars-wont-render-data

Comment: adding .lean() to the end of limit(3) make it work! thanks a lot man, modify your answer and ill mark it as correct!

Comment: That's  great :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you did

```
{{#each  dashboard }}
<p>
    {{temperatura}} //       // using just one, but both show me the 3 objects
    {{humedad}}
</p>
{{/each}}
```

?

Comment: i would get three empty <p> with no data of the array i have passed